# What are rules for naming encodings?

Tags: font-encodings, font-map

Consider this line from map file:

```
zpopr Optima "MyEncoding ReEncodeFont" <myenc.enc
```

What is the meaning of `MyEncoding`? Where is it used? Should this name have any particular format (for example when one wants to change default encoding of `cmr10.pfb`)?

Consider these lines from enc file:

```
/T1Encoding [
....
] def
```

What is the meaning of `T1Encoding`? Where is it used? Should this name have any particular format when one creates an encoding for a new font (for example, `lhr10`)?

Comment: the names should be unique. either dvips or pdftex (I have forgotten which) doesn't like it if you have myenc1.enc and myenc2.enc and both define a /myencencoding. That's why autoinst use random letters: AutoEnc_uima5pxttv4p6cnxhii3iw2jsh.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know how `<file.enc` differs from `<[file.enc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `MyEncoding` is just used internally in the PostScript/PDF to define the font that is referenced externally (`zpopr` in your example) in terms of an existing base font (`Optima`).

That said it is helpful to give the same name to the same encoding if used in multiple places.  There are two common name sources for encodings used in the tex setup, LaTeX encodings are described in encguide.pdf in (`texdoc encguide`) T1 encoding (usually accessed via `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc)` is the 8bit "Cork" encoding used which is the native encoding of the EC fonts and used for most European latin based scripts (as opposed to the OT1 encoding, the original 7bit TeX encoding used by cmr10).

The other source of encoding names is the Karl Berry font name scheme, this uses names like 8r (more or less latex's LY1) 8a (Adobe standard) see the comments at the top of each of

```
$ ls /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/
6w.enc       asexp.enc   q-cs-uni.enc   q-t2c-uni.enc       texmext.enc
7t.enc       dc.enc      q-ec-uni.enc   q-t5-uni.enc        texmital.enc
8a.enc       dvips.enc   q-l7x-uni.enc  q-texnansi-uni.enc  texmsym.enc
8r.enc       ec.enc      q-qx-uni.enc   q-ts1-uni.enc       texnansx.enc
ad.enc       extex.enc   q-rm-uni.enc   qx.enc
ansinew.enc  funky.enc   q-t2a-uni.enc  stormex.enc
asex.enc     odvips.enc  q-t2b-uni.enc  tex256.enc
```

Comment: AFAIU, `MyEncoding` selects array name in `myenc.enc` (there may be several arrays in `myenc.enc`). Is it correct?

Comment: Do you know how `<file.enc` differs from `<[file.enc`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko see `texdoc dvips` page 47 To make your intentions clear, you can also use ‘<[’ to explicitly indicate you
are downloading an encoding vector, as in:

Answer (score 0):

Extract from `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/ansinew.enc`:

```
% SAMPLE USAGE (in `psfonts.map' file for DVIPS):
% 
% lbr LucidaBright "WindowsANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" <ansinew.enc <lbr.pfb
%
% This tells DVIPS that the font called `lbr' in TeX has PostScript 
% FontName `LucidaBright.'  It asks DVIPS to expand the file `lbr.pfb'
% into PFA form, to include the attached `ansinew.enc' encoding vector,
% and to actually reencode the font based on that encoding vector.
```

In pdfTeX, entire "... ReEncodeFont" field is ignored.